# log file timestamp in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a script that I run as such:

```
nohup ksh93 -c ". ./cmdtst_multi.ksh" > prcsstst.log
```

is there a way to add a timestamp to each line it writes in the log file in the command? Or inside of my script, do I have to include the timestamp in each of the "echo" functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally, I wrote a thing to do just that a few week ago.

The command itself is:

```
gawk '{ print strftime("[%H:%M:%S]"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

Or if you don't have gawk:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -ne 'print strftime("[%H:%M:%S] ", localtime()).$_;'
```

---

You can integrate it as such:

```
nohup ksh93 -c ". ./cmdtst_multi.ksh" | either_example_above > prcstst.log
```

Comment: Note: for the `gawk` command the `fflush()` is required.  By default `gawk` will buffer the output which makes monitoring log files troublesome.

Comment: i think all of the answer can work...but you were the first to respond :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do it from the script you will have the same time stamp for each output line of the script. You can do this for example by using awk:

```
nohup ksh93 -c ". ./cmdtst_multi.ksh" | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); } > prcsstst.log
```

If your script is running for a long time and you are interested in the exact time stamp for each echo, you will have to modify each echo. You can do this by using the awk command above, but you can also use "date" instead

Answer (score 0):

You may need to unbuffer your ksh script side of the pipe. Without testing, I'd guess

```
nohup ksh -c '
    stdbuf --output=L ksh -c ". ./cmdtst_multi.ksh" | 
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        print "$(date "+[%T]") - $line"
    done
' > prctst.log
```

`stdbuf` is in GNU coreutils, so your "unix" platform may not have it. If you have `expect` installed, you may have `unbuffer` in your PATH that does the same job.